# Selenium with python, click button is not work?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, click

I am new in python and Selenium, here is my code
Using pyCharm and python3, I want go to https://www.lambdatest.com/ and click "Pricing" button at top, I can open the browser but click button is not work. may I know anything wrong? thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Pricing').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the full working code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

# Accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Allow Cookie']"))).click()

# Click on Pricing
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Pricing']"))).click()
```

Comment: thank you so much, the coding is working, and yes I have to use the "find element by X path" and accept cookie and wait for the item is clickable (still learning). thanks sir